# Primefaces graphicImage without ?pfdrid_c=true

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am trying to render a graphic image in primefaces but always returns a 404.
In Chrome Debug I can see the address image like this:

`/UltracarWeb/Images/1427303591376_image.png?pfdrid_c=true"`

Using the Chrome Debug I changed for:

```
/UltracarWeb/Images/1427303591376_image.png?pfdrid_c=false" , then the image is rendered.
```

I call the graphicImage in xhtml this way:

```
 <p:graphicImage  style="max-width: 110px; max-height: 140px;"
                 value="#{product.PhotoUrl}"                                                          
                 rendered="#{not empty product.Url}">                                                        
</p:graphicImage>
```

I already tryed with cache false and true, and still not work.

The url is not empty because I checked this in the Debug.
Debugging the java code I saw the product.url without the ?pfdrid_c=true, but in browser Debug the ?pfdrid_c=true appears.

This ?pfdrid_c=true  is a primefaces constant  do refers the dynamic cache, but I don't know how can I remove it?

Comment: `<p:graphicImage cache="false" .../>` but if you get `404` then, this should not be related. There should be something else which is invisible in the post.

Comment: Well...the primefaces adds the ?pfdrid_c=true automaticaly, without it, the image is rendered.

Comment: If the image URL is correct then, the image should be displayed as usual regardless of the value of `cache`. Have you ever tried to make a hard page refresh (`F5` on most browsers) or clear the browser's history?

Comment: When I refresh the page with F5, the image is rendered.

Comment: That non-existing image (perhaps, it was deleted from the physical location on disk in the middle) was directly being served from a cache (before `F5` was struck).

Comment: I checked the disk and the image exists, but withou the ?pfdrid_c=true.

I did a test, by the Chrome Debug I change the image url of :/UltracarWeb/Images/1427303591376_image.png?pfdrid_c=false to :
/UltracarWeb/Images/1427303591376_image.png and the image is rendered...well..thanks for availability in help

Comment: That image is served from the cache while using `cache="true"`. That image  `/UltracarWeb/Images/1427303591376_image.png` should exist in the cache and the browser somehow might have remembered it as a non-existing image - it might have been deleted in the middle or so. [See for example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23982048/1391249).

Comment: Thanks, I will see the link and try to solve this problem.

Comment: No. That link is an example. It is only needed, when you need to re-request an image (resource) on every page load/page refresh. This should not be the matter in your case.

Answer (score 2):

I have had the same problem with this component of primefaces to images, because it adds the parameter `?pfdrid_c=true` used to control the `Cache-Control`

I was using it like this (primefaces element):

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"...>


<p:graphicImage value="#{product.PhotoUrl} />
```

and I chose to use this other jsf element that works perfectly for me since it does not introduce parameter:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"...>


<h:graphicImage value="#{product.PhotoUrl} />
```

This works only if the value is a String representing an URL but this does not work if the value is a `DefaultStreamedContent`. This isn't supported by `<h:graphicImage>`